# In Python 2, how to copy list of complex nested elements by value, not reference, regardless of the list's content

Tags: python, list, reference

I come across some great questions and answers about copying lists by reference vs by value ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382487/copy-a-list-of-list-by-value-and-not-reference)). Unfortunately, none of proposed solutions removes the reference from all the nested structures (tried `b = a[:]`,  `b = list(a)`, `copy.copy`...). My last hope was `copy.deepcopy` but it doesn't work for nested structures when there is an array somewhere inside (I am working on openpyxl columns). I get this error on the bottom of the stack:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'array.array'
```

My question is: **is it possible to create a full copy of list `a` without any references, regardless of what is nested inside `a`?**

Comment: Your error is not due to the `deepcopy`. Rather the fact that you are trying to use it as the `key` to a `dict`, which requires the `key` be a hashable type.

Comment: You call `copy.deepcopy` once on the entire structure and everything is copied recursively: `b = copy.deepcopy(a)`

Comment: yet, the `copy.py` python module is the origin of the error.

Comment: I think I didn't understand you guys right. @CoryKramer, probably there is some dict inside this structure but why would it matter? @COLDSPEED this is what I did. In my case: `tmp_columns = deepcopy([r for r in ws.columns])` and it throws `TypeError`.

Comment: @Artur Just do `tmp_columns = deepcopy(ws.columns)`.

Comment: ws.columns is a generator so I can't do it directly. If I split it to separate lines the result is the same (`tmp_columns = [r for r in ws.columns]` `tmp_columns_no_reference = deepcopy(tmp_columns)` also returns `TypeError`)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `deepcopy` is what you need. The issue is that the `StyleArray` class doesn't implement `__deepcopy__`.

The following fix seems to do the job:

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    return self.__copy__()
```

NB: the `__copy__` is already a copy by value (to be checked).

It also answers your more generic question: in order to make a full copy of a nested structure, the non-standard nested elements must somehow indicate how to copy themselves.

Comment: Thank you! For answer and explanation. Let me check this tommorow at work and I will mark it as answer after.

Comment: I looked deeper in `copy` module, and the docs say `This version does not copy types like module, class, function, method,
nor stack trace, stack frame, nor file, socket, window, nor array, nor
any similar types.` Is it the right way to modify array module with this deepcopy definition?

Comment: One good way to find out would be to test: clone, change the style (`StyleArray` state) in some way, and compare against original. My guess is that `copy` module doesn't copy arrays by default, since it might silently introduce memory and time penalties. Anyway it doesn't mean that's forbidden or "wrong" to do it.