# change an array in a 2d matrix initialized with inf

Tags: python

version: python 3

The code is straight forward

```
dp = [[float('inf')] * 3] * 3

dp[0][0] = 1
```

what I get

- [[1, inf, inf], [1, inf, inf], [1, inf, inf]]

what I expect to get

- [[1, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf]]

Any clues ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list * number` means not a copy of the list but `number` references to the same list (same memory location). That's why mutating one of the three lists will mutate also the other ones.

A solution could be (create the lists using a loop):

```py
dp = [[float("inf")] * 3 for i in range(3)]
```

See also: [Copy a list of list by value and not reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382487/copy-a-list-of-list-by-value-and-not-reference)