# Python class with key value pair not updating

Tags: python, json, class

I have a `json` file from which the Python script reads key and value pairs and stores in `notes` class variable. One of the key in `notes` is called `project_suites`. I am trying to duplicate this `project_suites` key multiple times depending on sub-directories count in the script location. For each duplicate, I am including `input_path` and `output_path`:

```
# project_folders contains list of sub-directories            
for idx, path in enumerate(project_folders):
    # relative_path gets path without the test_path
    relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, test_path)

    # split the relative_path into a list
    path_list     = os.path.normpath(relative_path).split(os.path.sep)

    # create new sub-key and assign path_list
    notes.values['project_suites'][idx]['input_path'] = path_list
    notes.values['project_suites'][idx]['output_path'] = path_list
    print(notes.values['project_suites'][idx])
```

This seems to be working with the above `print` in the loop outputs the following:

```
{'recursive': True, 'project': 'p.prj', 'grid': 'grid.i', 'input_path': ['01-zdir', '01-no-drag'], 'output_path': ['01-zdir', '01-no-drag']}
{'recursive': True, 'project': 'p.prj', 'grid': 'grid.i', 'input_path': ['01-zdir', '02-const-drag'], 'output_path': ['01-zdir', '02-const-drag']}
{'recursive': True, 'project': 'p.prj', 'grid': 'grid.i', 'input_path': ['01-zdir', '03-WenYu-drag'], 'output_path': ['01-zdir', '03-WenYu-drag']}
```

After the above `for` loop, I am doing

```
print(notes.values['project_suites'])
```

This gives me the following output:

```
[{'recursive': True, 'project': 'p.prj', 'grid': 'grid.i', 'input_path': ['01-zdir', '03-WenYu-drag'], 'output_path': ['01-zdir', '03-WenYu-drag']}, {'recursive': True, 'project': 'p.prj', 'grid': 'grid.i', 'input_path': ['01-zdir', '03-WenYu-drag'], 'output_path': ['01-zdir', '03-WenYu-drag']}, {'recursive': True, 'project': 'p.prj', 'grid': 'grid.i', 'input_path': ['01-zdir', '03-WenYu-drag'], 'output_path': ['01-zdir', '03-WenYu-drag']}]
```

Basically, the `input_path` and `output_path` seem to have only the last `path_list` for everyone. Any reason why this inconsistency is occurring?

Comment: It seems like `notes.values['project_suites']` has a bunch of references to the same object, but since you didn't provide code that can reproducible the problem, all we can do is guess. (I noticed you linked to [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your bio here...)

Comment: @Mark : Apparently, the issue is to do with `list` duplicating which I did not show here. I did `deepcopy` and things seem to be working fine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382487/copy-a-list-of-list-by-value-and-not-reference